# What is unstructured data and what produce it?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I read a lot of articles about unstructured data and that NoSql allows us to store it, but I don't can find a clear explanation of how we can get unstructured data.

On the home page of MongoDb, I found the next examples of unstructured data

1. **Email**: Email message
2. **Text files**: This category includes word processing documents, spreadsheets, presentations, email, and log files
3. **Mobile and communications data**: Text messages, phone recordings, collaboration software, Chat, and Instant Messaging.

But for me not clear why we can't **specify field** and put email text or some text file in this field. Text file or email is no more than long text with type string, and why MongoDB specify it as the unstructured file is not clear to me

Answer (score 0):

The sentence from same page try to explain it:
Unstructured data, in contrast, **doesn’t fit into these sorts of pre-defined data models**. It can’t be stored in an RDBMS. And **because it comes in so many formats,** it’s a real challenge for conventional software to ingest, process, and analyze. Simple content searches can be undertaken across textual unstructured data with the right tools .